Deploying prefixed metadata with DevOps Center/CLI: "Only components in the same namespace as the organization can be created through the API"
I'm trying to wrap my head around how metadata-driven deployments (e.g. through DevOps Center or the sf CLI) can coexist with metadata created by managed packages. For example, our org installed the Ring Central package in a sandbox. This package, with the prefix rcsfl, created a lot of new web links under the Contacts and Tasks. All of these weblinks have the rcsfl__ metadata prefix, like so:
Task/webLinks/rcsfl__Send_SMS_Opp.webLink-meta.xml    `

When I try to deploy this metadata into our staging sandbox, the deployment fails with this error:

Cannot create a new component with the namespace: rcsfl. Only components in the same namespace as the organization can be created through the API."

How am I supposed to keep these changes from managed packages in sync with sandbox further down the deployment pipeline? Or do I need to do all my managed package stuff by hand in production?
